# NFS & JAVA (/etc/exports)

Tags: unix, mount, nfs

I am trying to mount a PC on unix.
I found a software called "mount" and I edited the unix /etc/exports file to recognize the PC ip (or dns name).

I perfrom mount, and it is ok. I don't even have to specify a password. But, occasionally the mount stops working and I have to re-mount again.

I was wondering two things:

1. Can I use "net use" command to mount (without specifying the username and password for the unix - given the /etc/exports recognizes the mounting PC)?
2. Whether I use the mount or "net use", they require me to set a drive letter for the NFS directory. Is there anyway instead to write some java code instead of both "mount"/"net use" to access my remote dir (again, given the /etc/exports recognizes the PC from which the java is run).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Microsoft-provided Windows NFS client it does handle UNC style paths to NFS exports, that is in the format \\unix_server\export\path.  This would allow you to access the NFS files without mounting a drive letter.  There is a limitation with this NFS client and UNC paths however, which is multipart exports are not supported.  See this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772500.aspx#BKMK_IcannotaccessamultipartexportusingaUniversalNamingConventionpath) for details.